# jquery using .data method to trigger elements in DOM

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use a system like bootstrap, but using `.data()` method to attach a function to the dom for a specific element.

For instance if an element has:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropbox">Click me</a>
```

Can I just jQuery to triggle a function to these elements?

```
 var dropBox = $('a').data('toggle', 'dropbox');
```

When I `console.log(dropBox)` it returns all `a` on the page.  I'm trying to make this work on buttons and `('a')` elements I write this on for `.on('click'...` and log `this` and I get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dropBox = $('a[data-toggle="dropbox"]');
```

or

```
var dropBox = $('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('toggle')=='dropbox';
});
```